# Valgrind stack trace not proper in ARM machine

Tags: ubuntu, arm, malloc, valgrind, debug-backtrace

I am running valgrind on simple program on **ARM machine(ubuntu)** not getting proper stack trace in valgrind report, using latest valgrind **(Valgrind-3.13.0)** on machine.

HEAP SUMMARY:
in use at exit: 2,400 bytes in 6 blocks
total heap usage: 7 allocs, 1 frees, 3,424 bytes allocated

2,400 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
at 0x4845BFC: **malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)**

LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 2,400 bytes in 6 blocks
indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

As you can see for malloc proper stack trace is not coming in report, can any one please help on this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: valgrind 3.13.0 is a quite old valgrind release, and many improvements/bug fixes  have been done. You better download the latest release (3.19.0), build it and try with this newer version. Also, be sure to compile your program with debug info (-g).

Comment: Same thing happens to me, with version 3.21.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so is not stripped of its debug symbols.